# Mobile Web App - combines with exist web app or separate them

Tags: jsf

The company I work for already has a fully functional web app that is written in java using JSF framework.  I'm now in the process of creating a mobile version of this web app and having some general questions on where to put this mobile  web app.

1. Should this mobile web app be a separate project, packaged in a
   different war, and installed as separate app in server or should it
   be part of the existing web app, packaged in the same war, and
   installed as same app in server?
2. Should the mobile web app uses existing web app's jsf Manage Beans? 
   For example, we already have an order entry app that consists of
   several jsf Manage Beans and jsf pages.  To create the mobile
   version of this app, should I simply create new mobile version of
   jsf pages but uses all the exist jsf Manage Beans in those mobile
   jsf pages?  Will I run into problem because mobile web app's
   page-flow might be different from the web app's page-flow?  But if I
   don't reuse, it seems like there will be a lot of duplicate code.

Comment: Interesting question, probably not suitable for StackOverflow.

Comment: Nope, programmers.se comes more close.

Comment: any suggestion on better site for this type of question?